# Unity2D Moving along grid lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making what is essentially a board game within Unity 2D. The player will be able to move their pieces along a grid (see below). The larger circular sprites are the pieces, which the player can click on, then click a gridPoint (the small squares) to move to it.

[image]

I've created the grid by using empty gameobjects (I've rendered a sprite on them for visual help) at each intersection. These are the points where players can move between. The distance between the points varies, though the horizontal distance is always 1.

The full functionality would be...

1. A player clicks on a piece,
2. A preview area of where the piece can move to is shown.
3. Player clicks on a valid grid point where the piece should move to.
4. Grid piece moves to new point.

First of all, have I created this in the right way? I need the grid to be accurate, as it will be populated with an accurate sky map. Currently this grid is accurate.

Assuming this is the right way of doing it, how do I, when a piece is selected, work out which grid points are within range? Say a piece can move 4 spaces, then any space 4 grid points away from origin (horizontally, vertically and diagonally) can be moved to. I'd also need to count how many spaces the piece has moved.

I also need to make the piece travel from it's original position, to the new grid point, via grid points using the shortest route.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are many solution for this, but let's keep it simple!!
simple overview of your solution step!!

- If your grid is fixes size(i.e fix height and width unity length), then put custom placeholder (empty gameobject)in intersection point
- detect the swipe detection(assuming you working with this mechanism) from current tapping piece to direction.
- using any tween library(i suggest DoTween library from unity asset store, it's free and absolutely amazing.)move your piece to that placeholder.

Now bit more in depth Understanding!!
please refer the below reference.

- [initial condition of any type of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxiND.png)
- after creating the grid, you can put empty gameobject as an placeholder in between grid(you can make it invisible- i.e make it alpha 0 of image property!)
- [placeholder in between gap of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTBrx.png)
- you can make you piece(player) child of any of these placeholder.
- you will detect the swipe or even tap mechanism and check weather in what ever direction you swapping or in which invisible placeholder you tapping, has any child??
- if yes, that means that placeholder is already occupied with other piece(player). so no logic to move your current piece. so ignore the swipe.
- if no, that means placeholder is empty, so its valid move.
- using any tween library, from current placeholder position to desired placeholder, move your piece(player).
- after reaching to desired placeholder, make that piece the child of that desired placeholder(using setparent(desiredplaceholder.gameobject.transform.position) kinda code)

and you done!!

hope you find this helpful!!